# Disposing the members that implement IDisposable

Tags: c#, idisposable, nullreferenceexception

In my Dispose methods (like the one below), everytime i want to call someObj.Dispose() i also have a check for someObj!=null.

Is that because of bad design on my part? 
Is their a cleaner way to ascertain that Dispose of all the members (implementing IDisposable) being used in an object is called without having a risk of NullReference exception ?

```
protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
               if (_splitTradePopupManager != null)
                {
                    _splitTradePopupManager.Dispose();
                }
             }
        }
```

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe someone else can chime in on this, but I don't personally think it's a design flaw -- just the safest way to do it.

That said, nothing's stopping you from wrapping your `null` check and `Dispose` call in a convenient method:

```
private void DisposeMember(IDisposable member)
{
    if (member != null)
        member.Dispose();
}
```

Then your `Dispose` method could look a bit cleaner:

```
protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        DisposeMember(_splitTradePopupManager);
        DisposeMember(_disposableMember2);
        DisposeMember(_disposableMember3);
    }
}
```

As an added bonus, this also resolves a potential race condition in your original code. If running in a multithreaded context, the `if (_field != null) _field.Dispose()` pattern can result in a `NullReferenceException` when `_field` is set to `null` between the check and the disposal (rare, but possible). Passing `_field` as an argument to a method such as `DisposeMember` copies the reference to a local variable in the method, eliminating this possibility, unlikely as it is.

Comment: Agreed with it not being a design flaw. Maybe I'm overly cautious, but I prefer to have a null-check even when I certifiably know that the object will never be null when it comes to disposables.

Comment: @ccomet: +1, i have the same thinking (overly cautious) at the back of mind while calling Dispose() on an object.

Answer (score 10):

I like @Dan Tao's solution, but it's much better as an extension method, imo:

```
public static void SafeDispose(this IDisposable obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
        obj.Dispose();
}
```

Now you can just call `member.SafeDispose()` on any `IDisposable` in your program without worry. :)

Comment: That wont throw a null reference exception when it tries to call the extension method? Edit-- I wrote a quick test app, and it works great!

Comment: No, it won't.  I used a similar approach in a project (DisposeIfNotNull()).

Comment: Nope! Since the dot operator is just syntactic sugar for a static method, it works just fine. :)

Comment: This is one of the things i liked the most about extension methods. Unfortunately in my current project we ar working on 2.0, so no choice of extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Only you know the answer to this one!

Without seeing your entire class it's difficult for anyone else to tell if it's possible that those members will ever be null when `Dispose` is called.

(Of course, as a general rule it's always possible for a reference type or nullable value type to be null, so it's probably good practice to always include those null checks anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

The only other option I could think of would be to create a `DisposeParameter` helper method that has an object as it's parameter and only checks if it's null and otherwise Dispose it. That way you'd only need one line of code to dispose of it, but I'm not sure if it would make it more readable.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
    protected void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    { 
        if (disposing) 
        {
           //for all members.. 
           if (null != member && member is IDisposible) 
            { 
                member.Dispose(); 
            } 
         } 
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting here.

Comment: It wasn't me, but checking whether the member is a `IDisposable` is a bit silly, because a call to `member.Dispose()` would not compile when `member` was not a disposable type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349378/new-programming-jargon-you-coined/2430307#2430307  P.S. I did't downvote, but null != member just reminded me on that post ;)